# Grant Uri read permission also to files linked by html opened in browser with content:/// scheme

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

To open a file in a web brower, and avoid the `FileUriExposedException` from Oreo, I properly share files using `FileProvider` and Temporary URI Permissions. 
The problem is that the html file to open **contains a link to another companion file**, which worked fine with `file:///[...]` and fixed permission to read external memory in the destination app, but doesn't work with `content:///[...]` because of course temp permissions are only granted to the first file and not the second one.

Is there any way to grant temp read permission to another file too? Without resorting to manually granting permission for the other file to every suitable app, before the user select the app they actually want to use?

The present code, using itents for various browsers:

```
protected Uri getUriFromFile(File file)
{
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this,
            "com.whatever.example.fileprovider",
            file);
}

protected void openInWebBroser(File file, File linkedFile)
{   
    Uri uri = getUriFromFile(file);
    Uri linkedUri = getUriFromFile(linkedFile);

    // Firefox and html viewer
    Intent webIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    webIntent1.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html");
    webIntent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    // TODO somehow add also linkedUri, not to be open right now but to be added to permitted???

    // Chrome
    Intent webIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    webIntent2.setDataAndType(uri, "multipart/related");
    webIntent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    // Default android browser
    Intent webIntent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
    webIntent3.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html");
    webIntent3.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
    webIntent3.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    if(getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(webIntent1, 0).size() > 0)
    {
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(webIntent1, null);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { webIntent2, webIntent3 });          
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
    else if(getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(webIntent2, 0).size() > 0)
    {
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(webIntent2, null);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { webIntent3 });          
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
    else if(getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(webIntent3, 0).size() > 0)
    {
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(webIntent3, null);          
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
    else
    {
        // ... error management
    }
}
```

Comment: You better change the subject to: Chrome and other browsers dont show pictures from img/src tag if html page loaded from content scheme.

Comment: Yes. I've seen this too. If the html page is opened using the Storage Access Framework and obtaining a content scheme than browsers can display the text of the page. But they are unable to retrieve the relative image files mentioned in the src attrbute of the img tag. A shame!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with no answers and lacking better options, the best I could devise is to pre-authorize any available browser to read the linked file.

As for `revokeUriPermission()`, while the documentation insist you have to call it, it doesn't seem right to call it from the originating app (e.g. in `onDestroy()` when `isFinishing()`?): what happens if the originating app is closed while the browser still has it open? (When you use the intent, the permission is revoked when the destination app unwind the stack.) The documentation states that the permission is valid until the device is rebooted. That seems better than the alternatives. Opinions?

Is there a way to do so only for the app the user actually choose? (Without reimplementing the whole chooser.)

```
protected Uri getUriFromFile(File file)
{
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this,
            "com.whatever.example.fileprovider",
            file);
}

protected void openInWebBroser(File file, File linkedFile)
{   
    Uri uri = getUriFromFile(file);
    Uri linkedUri = null;
    if( linkedFile!= null )
        linkedUri = getUriFromFile(linkedFile);

    // Firefox and html viewer
    Intent webIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    webIntent1.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html");
    webIntent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    // Chrome
    Intent webIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    webIntent2.setDataAndType(uri, "multipart/related");
    webIntent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    // Default android browser
    Intent webIntent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
    webIntent3.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html");
    webIntent3.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
    webIntent3.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    // Pre-grant access to linkedUri for any candidate
    if( linkedUri != null )
    {
        Intent[] intents = new Intent[]{ webIntent1, webIntent2, webIntent3 };

        for( Intent intent : intents )
            for( ResolveInfo info : getPackageManager ().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0) )
                grantUriPermission(info.activityInfo.packageName, linkedUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }


    if(getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(webIntent1, 0).size() > 0)
    {
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(webIntent1, null);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { webIntent2, webIntent3 });          
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
    else if(getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(webIntent2, 0).size() > 0)
    {
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(webIntent2, null);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { webIntent3 });          
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
    else if(getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(webIntent3, 0).size() > 0)
    {
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(webIntent3, null);          
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
    else
    {
        // ... error management
    }
}
```